# iOS 9.0.2 Safari - Cannot open the page. Protocol error

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

I'm having an issue where users accessing my website using an iPhone with iOS 9.0.2 and Safari are experiencing an error on one particular page when submitting a form:

"Safari cannot open page. The error was: "The operation couldn't be completed. Protocol error".

The issue only seems to occur on iPhones running iOS 9.0.2 and using Safari. It does not occur on desktops, android tablets/phones or iPads (tested using Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, etc) nor does it occur on older versions of the iPhone iOS.

The error seems consistent, mostly, and can be repeated by going to:

1. Go to http://saltyunderground.com/TEST/category/berghia-nudibranch (make sure you aren’t signed in from a previous test)
2. Click on 1/4+ Inch Berghia Nudibranchs image link -> goes to Berghia product page
3. Click on Buy Now -> goes to Shopping cart page
4. Click on checkout -> Goes to sign-in / create account page
5. Click Create Account button -> goes to create account page
6. Fill out fields and click sign up button -> Goes back to checkout page showing new shipping address
7. Enter address and click Continue button -> PROTOCOL Error occurs.

This error seems pretty consistent and occurs whether you create an account or sign into an existing account. But only seems to occurs on the iPhone using Safari under iOS 9.0.2

I appreciate any help figuring this out, it has me perplexed to say the least.

Thanks

Comment: Why not update?